# Couchbase for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: package-management, couchdb

I can't find any site/document/issue for installing Couchbase for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I tried installing the deb package from their official site but I received an error, which states that `librtmp0 is not installed`. I tried to install the said lib but received a response the `librtmp0 has no installation candidate`. Probably because it is not available on 16.04. Does it mean that Couchbase is still not supported for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Couchbase is in the process of making it work for Ubuntu 16.04. See https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-19272.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Couchbase's issue tracker at https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-19272, it seems that Couchbase is still in the process of making Couchbase Server work on Ubuntu 16.04, so you are out of luck for the time being.

Comment: Ten months later, still no Ubuntu 16.04 - super slow release cycles, including annoying bugs.

Comment: Wish they had a tip jar other means just to get a dev version on ubuntu 16

Comment: Looks like the issue has been closed and there are builds for Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

[These](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/getting-started/installing.html) instructions worked for me.

Essentially download the `.deb` for the `14.04` version and install it via `dpkg`

Comment: This link is dead

Comment: I tried with the 12 and 14 versoin from their official site. both failed. service not found